# GLSL 1.20: GL error 0x0502 and 0x0501

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, minecraft

I'm creating shaders for minecraft.
I added a motion blur but there are 2 errors in the console thar are very strange:
GL error 0x0502
GL error 0x0501

So here is the code: http://pastebin.com/Z6VA9Vv7
I think it's a problem with the color or something like that...

Comment: These are the GL_INVALID_OPERATION and GL_INVALID_VALUE errors respectively, meaning you probably broke something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple - it's not at the line 394 you point to at http://pastebin.com/Z6VA9Vv7

> //Go to line 394 for the motion blur and error

but at line 422

```glsl
 color += texture2D(gcolor, coord);
```

(as one could figure out by using e.g. the [OpenGL / OpenGL ES Reference Compiler](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/)):

> ERROR: 0:422: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '4-component vector of
>   float' to '3-component vector of float' ERROR: 1 compilation errors. 
>   No code generated.

Your "color" was in line 327 declared as vec3

```glsl
vec3 color = texture2D(gaux2, texcoord.st + fake_refract * 0.005).rgb;
```

but at that very line 422 you try to assign the return value of texture2D, which is vec4, to it.

---

Appending a ".rgb" swizzle to the rhs expr in line 422

```glsl
color += texture2D(gcolor, coord).rgb;
```

solves that issue.

Comment: Thanks you a lot! But how do you have errors like this? What program do you use to find problems?

Comment: @user3752928: You have them too, you need to call `glGetShaderInfoLog (...)` rather than guessing what is wrong.

Comment: @user3752928: One "tool" is "accepting correct answers on SO". About the others I'll tell you later.

Comment: Thanks man! Sorry, I'm new here :s.

Comment: Never mind. Aside from the mentioned programmatic glGetShaderInfoLog() and getProgramInfoLog(), there's the "OpenGL / OpenGL ES Reference Compiler" I linked to at https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/ as a stand-alone tool. I cannot tell about its windoze flavors for sure, but with (Debian x86_64) Linux/gcc 4.8 that compiled and worked flawlessly. Happy hacking!

Comment: I added a ".rgb" like you said but there are withe shadows on the screen :s It's very strange...

Comment: There's is a "but" too much.

Comment: Without that bug fix your shader is plainly syntactically invalid. How you however fix the business logic of your shader - getting it to do what you want it to - is way beyond that scope.